# Are mass-bred chicken fed with hormones or other substances that, when you eat their meat, can have significant negative effect on your health?

Tags: medical-science, consumer-products, poland

My friend told me that chicken meat is unhealthy - presumably chicken are fed with hormones which can be unhealthy, as well as the meat could contain some added chemicals. My question applies to Poland. Could this claim be true? I mean "unprocessed" chicken meat - like chicken breasts, not chicken wursts, etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: there are different qualities of chicken meat, and many different conditions and definitions of "unhealthy". I am quite confident that if you raise your own chickens and eat meat only rarely, there will be minimum health effects. If you eat tons of processed meat (such as chicken wursts) then you probably are going to have some problems. There are too many right answers for this question.

Comment: @Sklivvz What I mean is more or less "Are mass-bred chicken fed with hormones or other substances that, when you eat their meat, can have significant negative effect on your health?". Is that better?

Comment: You need to edit your question, please. Also, do restrict this to a specific country (different countries = different restrictions)

Comment: @Sklivvz Of course - just wanted to make sure that my new question is better.

Comment: I've heard the same thing for beef. There may also be antibiotics and other medicines.